# sort date and time from a colletcion of list

Tags: java, sorting

sort date and time from a colletcion of list. The above code is working for date only , i need to work both date and time in descending order.

AssignDate is java util date and time is a string

```
for(AssignmentHistoryModal historyModal:modals){
                Collections.sort(historyModal.getAssignmentModals(), new Comparator<AssignmentModal>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(AssignmentModal a1, AssignmentModal a2) {

                        return (a2.getAssignDate().compareTo(a1.getAssignDate())) & a2.getTime().compareTo(a1.getTime());
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: What is `getassignDate` and `getTime` returning?  Java `Date` values are comparable.

Comment: What you suppose `&` means?

Comment: Please refere: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()

java.util.Date has a getTime method, which will return long time stamp of date. which can be comparable in your Collection.sort method. So, by just comparing time, i.e. miliseconds you will able to sort any date, with time a well

Comment: What is the format of the time string?

Comment: time format hhh:mm a

Comment: java.util.Date contains a point in time - not a date. If you compare them, it is useless to compare another time property. If you store only date part in the `assignDate` property, then it could work.

Answer (score 1):

The logic will be as follows:

1. Compare the dates first. If they are not equal (i.e compareTo returns 0) return that value.
2. If the dates are equal, use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the time strings to two `Date` objects. Return the compareTo of these date objects.

Comment: getTime  and getAssignDate is not a same function.

Comment: What do they return? What types of objects?